# How do I get started with image processing in dart?

Tags: image-processing, dart

Hello can anyone help me how to deal with image processing in dart?

Comment: There's a mention of dart-html5-samples below. If you are satisfied with that answer, can you approve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on client side, you can draw an image onto a canvas, read back the canvas pixels, and run your filter on them. See [Image Filters with Canvas](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) for some examples.

Comment: This example has already been ported to Dart.  See [dart-html5-samples](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-html5-samples/tree/master/web/canvas/imagefilters) and a live version [here](http://www.scribegriff.com/dartlang/html5-samples/imagefilters/)